# ios Swift Firebase sending irregular data

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

I have a collectionView and ı am getting firebase database data. My collectionView create send firebase indexpath.row. This row 0 , 1, 2, 3, ... but firebase response irregular data and ı see debug mod indexpath.row 16 , 3, 7 , 11...

what is the problem ?

I share my sample code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     print(indexPath.row) // 1, 2, 3, 4
                self.ref.child(userID!).child(self.islemString).child(String(indexPath.row + 1)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        // Get user value

                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        let asd = value?["xxx"] as? Int ?? 0

                        print(indexPath.row) // 16, 3, 7 ,9 

                        if(asd == 0) {
                            cell.imageKilit.image = UIImage(named: "kilit")

                        }
                        else{
                            cell.imageKilit.image = UIImage(named: "")

                        }


                    }

                    )

}
```

Comment: Your code line 3 is very cryptic. This takes different time for the index paths, so the in the closure you don't get them in the same order.

Comment: How do I solve it?

Comment: No need to solve it. The order should be non-critical.

Comment: How? Can you an example?

Comment: This approach is not going to work very well long term. If there are 100 rows in your table, the code is going to hit Firebase 100 times to load, waiting for the return round trip to populate each cell in your collection. It's much better to load all 100 at one time into an array, and then let the collection view update itself with a reloadData(). Also, scrolling and other activities are really going to suffer as is - again, loading the data you want or a section of data at a time (10 rows, then another 10 rows etc) is going to be a much better direction.

Comment: I agree with @Jay.

Comment: jay can you give example code?

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment from the OP asking for example code:

Here's one example but I don't know what's stored in your Firebase so we will just use a messages structure as an example

```
messages
  msg_0
    msg: "Hello!"
  msg_1
    msg: "Another msg
```

and when the app starts we will have this code in the viewDidLoad to initially populate an array which will be used as a datasource for our collectionView, tableView etc.

```
var messagesArray = [String]()
var ref = //set to your firebase database

func viewDidLoad() {
    let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages")
    messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let msgDict = child.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let msg = msgDict["msg"] as! String
            self.messagesArray.append(msg)
        }

        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

then, in the collection view delegate methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt in...
   let msg = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]
   //do something with the msg
}
```

As you can see, as your scroll through the tableView, it's only pulling data from the dataSource array and not constantly hitting Firebase for each row of data. In this case we are using a simple string but it could be an array of message objects which could contain the message, the name of the sender and even their image.